# How to execute multiple SQL commands at once in pd.read_sql_query?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pymysql

Let me create an use case to discuss on.

```
CREATE  DATABASE sample;
USE sample;
CREATE TABLE quote (
  `id` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` text ,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `close` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ;

INSERT INTO quote (`code`, `date`, `close`)
VALUES ('epm', '20200824', 2.64); 
INSERT INTO quote (`code`, `date`, `close`)
VALUES ('dss', '20200824', 6.4);
```

It is simple to execute only one sql command with sqlalchemy.

```
import pandas as pd 
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
user = 'root'
mysql_pass = 'your mysql passwd'
mysql_ip = '127.0.0.1'
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}:3306".format(user,mysql_pass,mysql_ip))
cmd_one_line_sql = 'select * from sample.quote;'
df = pd.read_sql_query(cmd_one_line_sql,con = engine)
df 
   id code        date  close
0   1  epm  2020-08-24   2.64
1   2  dss  2020-08-24   6.40
```

I get the desired result,now the cmd contains multiple sql commands,for simplicity,it contains only two lines

```
cmd_multi_lines_sql = 'use sample;select * from quote;'
```

The `cmd_multi_lines_sql` just split `cmd_one_line_sql` as two.
I rewrite the code snippet according to manual:
[execute many sql commands with sqlalchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#multiple-result-sets)

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
user = 'root'
mysql_pass = 'your mysql passwd'
mysql_ip = '127.0.0.1'
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}:3306".format(user,mysql_pass,mysql_ip))
connection = engine.raw_connection()
cmd_multi_lines_sql = 'use sample;select * from quote;'
try:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(cmd_multi_lines_sql)
    results_one = cursor.fetchall()
finally:
    connection.close()
```

Get the below error info:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 517, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 732, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1075, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 684, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 220, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'select * from quote' at line 1")
```

Another try:

```
vim  /tmp/test.sql
use sample;
select * from quote;

#write the commands in `/tmp/test.sql`
f = open('/tmp/test.sql','r')
cmd = f.read() 
df = pd.read_sql_query(cmd, con = engine)
```

It output the same error info.How to fix it?

Comment: If you didn't edit the error message that you got, then you cmd variable (or text file) obviously contains the 'cmd commands here' string.
If you edited it, it's hard to help you without knowing what the sql error is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issues you face are:

1. You need to pass the `MULTI_STATEMENTS` flag to PyMySQL, and
2. `read_sql_query` assumes that the first result set contains the data for the DataFrame, and that may not be true for an anonymous code block.

You can create your own PyMySQL connection and retrieve the data like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
from pymysql.constants import CLIENT

conn_info = {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 3307,
    "user": "root",
    "password": "toot",
    "database": "mydb",
    "client_flag": CLIENT.MULTI_STATEMENTS,
}

cnxn = pymysql.connect(**conn_info)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()

sql = """\
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (id int primary key, txt varchar(20)) 
    ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
INSERT INTO tmp (id, txt) VALUES (1, 'foo'), (2, 'ΟΠΑ!');
SELECT id, txt FROM tmp;
"""
crsr.execute(sql)

num_tries = 5
result = None
for i in range(num_tries):
    result = crsr.fetchall()
    if result:
        break
    crsr.nextset()

if not result:
    print(f"(no result found after {num_tries} attempts)")
else:
    df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=[x[0] for x in crsr.description])
    print(df)
    """console output:
       id   txt
    0   1   foo
    1   2  ΟΠΑ!
    """
```

**(Edit) Additional notes:**

Note 1: As mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63641877/2144390), you can use the `connect_args` argument to SQLAlchemy's `create_engine` method to pass the `MULTI_STATEMENTS` flag. If you need a SQLAlchemy `Engine` object for other things (e.g., for `to_sql`) then that might be preferable to creating your own PyMySQL connection directly.

Note 2: `num_tries` can be arbitrarily large; it is simply a way of avoiding an endless loop. If we need to skip the first *n* empty result sets then we need to call `nextset` that many times regardless, and once we've found the non-empty result set we `break` out of the loop.

Comment: Wonderful! `df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=[x[0] for x in crsr.description])`,excelent!

Comment: Wish developer on SQLAlchemy to upgrade to support  MULTI_STATEMENTS' sql.

Comment: How can i send you 250 reputation bounty?

Comment: @showkey - I appreciate the thought, but don't worry about it. I'm glad you got a satisfactory solution to your issue.

Answer (score 6):

After some research and asking  at github
the answer is obvious

you need to pass the needed parameters with

```
connect_args=
```

And the parameter since sqlalchemy

is

```
{"client_flag": MULTI_STATEMENTS}
```

So your python code locks like his

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql
from pymysql.constants.CLIENT import MULTI_STATEMENTS
user = 'root'
mysql_pass = 'testpassword'
mysql_ip = 'localhost'
cmd = 'SELECT * FROM table1;SELECT * FROM test'

engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}:3306/testdb1?charset=utf8".format(user,mysql_pass,mysql_ip),connect_args={"client_flag": MULTI_STATEMENTS})
connection = engine.raw_connection()

try:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(cmd)
    results_one = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.nextset()
    results_two = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
finally:
    connection.close()
```

But with this solution you need to know before hand which queries  you run.

If you want to be **more flexible**, with dynamic sql statements

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
user = 'root'
mysql_pass = 'testpassword'
mysql_ip = 'localhost'
cmd = 'SELECT * FROM table1;SELECT * FROM test'
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}:3306/testdb1?charset=utf8".format(user,mysql_pass,mysql_ip))
connection = engine.raw_connection()
splitstring = cmd.split(";")
ges_resultset = []
try:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    for cmdoneonly in splitstring:
        cursor.execute(cmdoneonly)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        ges_resultset.append(results) 
    cursor.close()
finally:
    connection.close()
```

Where you can check every single command and know how python can react to it

- SELECT need to get the result set
- INSERT DELETE CREATE you don't(there are more, but you get the gist)

Comment: See [my comment to another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63596111/how-to-execute-multiple-sql-commands-at-once-in-pd-read-sql-query#comment112549034_63642842) re: splitting anonymous code blocks on the semicolon character. It doesn't always work, at least not with T-SQL.

Comment: this is a question about mysql and pymysql and both work, as intended, for sql server i couldn't find any solution  at all t that support multi query for sql server. But feel free to enlighten me

Comment: SQL Server supports anonymous code blocks by default (at least in any circumstances that I have encountered) so there is no need to explicitly enable "multiple statements".

Comment: that enablng is specific to py,ysql and differs from driver to driver massivly. I doubt that we could make a universal code ad hoc, but that would alofftopic here

Comment: How can i send you 250 reputation bounty?

Comment: accept the answer , upvote it and then click  on the 250 on the left side under the counter.

Answer (score 0):

@Gord Thompson,i make a little improvement to set num_tries automatically:

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
from pymysql.constants import CLIENT

conn_info = {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 3306,
    "user": "root",
    "password": "your mysql passwd",
    "client_flag": CLIENT.MULTI_STATEMENTS,
}

cnxn = pymysql.connect(**conn_info)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()

sql = """\
create database sample;
USE sample;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (id int primary key, txt varchar(20)) 
    ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
INSERT INTO tmp (id, txt) VALUES (1, 'foo'), (2, 'ΟΠΑ!');
SELECT id, txt FROM tmp;
SELECT txt FROM tmp;
"""

crsr.execute(sql)
num_tries = sql.count(';') if sql.endswith(';') else sql.count(';') + 1


for i in range(num_tries):
    result = crsr.fetchall()
    if result:
        df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=[x[0] for x in crsr.description])
        print(df)
    crsr.nextset()
```

@nbk:when the `cmd` contain many sql statements,to execute your code may encounter such issue as :

```
pymysql.err.InternalError: (1065, 'Query was empty')
```

Make a little improvement based on your code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
user = 'root'
mysql_pass = 'your mysql passwd'
mysql_ip = 'localhost'

sql = """\
create database sample;
USE sample;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (id int primary key, txt varchar(20)) 
    ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
INSERT INTO tmp (id, txt) VALUES (1, 'foo'), (2, 'ΟΠΑ!');
SELECT id, txt FROM tmp;
SELECT txt FROM tmp;
"""

engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}:3306".format(user,mysql_pass,mysql_ip))

connection = engine.raw_connection()

splitstring = sql.split(";")
try:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    for cmdoneonly in splitstring:
        if cmdoneonly.strip():
            cursor.execute(cmdoneonly)
            results = cursor.fetchall()
            if results :
                df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=[x[0] for x in cursor.description])
                print(df)
    cursor.close()
finally:
    connection.close()
```

- it is necessary to add a determine statement `if cmdoneonly.strip():` to avoid `1065:Query was empty` error.
- it is a wonderful statement `df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=[x[0] for x in cursor.description])` learning from `@Gord Thompson`.

Comment: Be aware that some SQL dialects (e.g., T-SQL) can be quite lax about requiring that statements be terminated with semicolons so simply splitting the text to count statements is not always guaranteed to work.